# comparing multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to compare two mutlidimensional arrays. The content of two arrays are as follows:

```
 $array1 = array (
 array(name=>"name", lastname => "example"),
 array(name=>"name")
 array(name=>"name", address => "exampleaddress")
 );

   $array2 = array
  (
   array(name=>1, lastname => 2, address => 3),

  );
```

now i want to compare the two arrays and form a new array as such as

```
 $array3 = array ([0]=>1, [1]=>2, [2]=>1 , [3] =>1, [4]=>3);
```

array3 contains values which is a result of comparing keys of array 1 and array 2 and inserting the values from array 2 that relates to keys in array. My question is that how can i generate array 3. I have done it on a normal array but having problem doing it in a multi dimensional array. Thanks very much for the help.

EDITED:

Have tried this:

```
    foreach ($array2 as $array2) {
        $new = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
    }

   $sum = array_sum($new);

  return $sum;
```

Comment: please see the edited version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably neater ways but you can simply loop and build up array 3:

```
$array3 = array();
foreach($array1 as $item){
    foreach($item as $key => $value){
        $array3[] = $array2[0][$key];//Assumes there will always be an entry for $key in $array2
    }
}
print_r($array3);
```

In your example array2 is an array containing a single array hence the use of `$array2[0][$key]`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to have in array3? Could you give an example based on arr1 & arr2?

If you want to find the intersect based on the key 'name' you can use the following code:

```
$array1 = array (
    array('name'=>"a", 'lastname' => "example"),
    array('name'=>"b"),
    array('name'=>"c", 'address' => "exampleaddress"),
    array('name'=>"d", 'lastname' => 'x'),
);  

$array2 = array
(
    array("name"=>"a", 'lastname' => 'x', 'address' => 'example'),
);


$intersect = array_uintersect($array1, $array2, 'compareDeepValue');
print_r($intersect);

function compareDeepValue($val1, $val2)
{
   return strcmp($val1['name'], $val2['name']);
}

// based on the comment received
$array2 = array
(
    array('name'=>1, 'lastname' => 3, 'address' => 2),

);

$array3 = array();
foreach ($array2[0] as $key => $rowID)
{
    $array3[] = $array1[$rowID][$key];
}
```

Comment: I would like values of array 2 based on matching keys.

Comment: Thus, array2 has key record relation? The key 'name' relates to the first record in array1? (Keep in mind that array index start at zero). I've editted the answer, check after the comment.